Errores en la actualización de Drupal a la versión 10
Estoy haciendo una actualización desde Drupal 9.3.8 a la versión 10 y me ha dado el típico pantallazo blanco con el siguiente mensaje. ¿alguna idea de cómo solucionarlo?
The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later.
Error: Class "Drupal\Driver\Database\mysql\Connection" not found in Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection() (line 460 of /home/aul/www/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Database/Database.php).
Drupal\Core\Database\Database::openConnection('default', 'default') (Line: 191)
Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection('default')
call_user_func_array('Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection', Array) (Line: 77)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'database') (Line: 179)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('database', 1) (Line: 226)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->resolveServicesAndParameters(Array) (Line: 60)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\PhpArrayContainer->createService(Array, 'cache.container') (Line: 179)
Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('cache.container') (Line: 576)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->getCachedContainerDefinition() (Line: 965)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->initializeContainer() (Line: 515)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->boot() (Line: 739)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

